# Is it possible to make a RAID of multiple WD elements external drives

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, raid

I have about 10 2tb WD Elements 2.5 WD green external hard drives (WD20NMVW). I want to know if I could make something useful out of them.

The best would be to be able to use them for a data archive or backup server for example by using a RAID.

In particular is it possible to do something with the usb port without having to do some soldering work?

I have seen that other have posted related questions but they do not fully cover my question.

Thank you!

Comment: Sure. Probably need a powered hub though, especially if the host is gonna be a RPi or so.

Comment: What OS do you want to use? Do you plan to run a bootable OS from one (or more) of these disks? In Linux you can do a lot with LVM (or Btrfs, or Zfs, I think). USB may limit the overall throughput, but not really the options; especially if your bootable OS is elsewhere.

Comment: These are 'native USB', no?

Answer (score 0):

> In particular is it possible to do something with the usb port without having to do some soldering work?

That question is pretty vague!

As far as I know there is no hidden fast SATA connector inside the disk housing that you could unlock somehow.

You just have to plug in the USB cables of your disks into a linux machine and configure your RAID setup.

When doing so with 10 disks without a dedicated power supply all electric load of those disks will apply to the mainboard which might have to deliver over 10 x 1,1A = 11A on the 5V branch.
I measured a spike of 1,1A. Because of the low frequency of my equipment, the peak may be much higher.

To see that the startup did not fail despite the high initial current load check if every device is visible within your linux machine.